# Understanding the Purpose of Mock Testing in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm currently learning Jest for testing my JavaScript code, and I've come across the concept of mock testing. However, I'm having trouble understanding the need for it. In my mock tests, I'm defining the expected result of a function, which makes me wonder why mock testing is necessary.

For instance, if I'm already defining the expected result of a function, that's mean I already know the result. So, why do we use mock testing in the first place?

I'd appreciate some insights into the practical reasons for incorporating mock testing into my testing practices and how it contributes to writing effective tests using Jest. Examples or real-world scenarios where mock testing is indispensable would be especially helpful. Thank you!